# R: combining multiple datasets together efficiently

Tags: r

I'm new to R so I'm still trying to figure things out.

I've got multiple raw datasets called with headers `region` and `populationXXXX`. The XXXX in the population header is the year.

All of the datasets have the exact same values in the `region` column, the only difference is the values in the `population` column which differ by year.

For example my first data set looks like this:

```
  Region          Population2000
1 Central Coast   85,000  
2 South Coast     3,000
```

My second dataset looks like this:

```
  Region          Population2001
1 Central Coast   80,000  
2 South Coast     4,000
```

I have 8 of these datasets (spanning from 2000 to 2007, and I would like to join them all into one and to look like this (I've only included the first two years):

```
  Region          Population2000   Population2001
1 Central Coast   85,000           80,000
2 South Coast     3,000            4,000
```

Is there an efficient way to do this without using multiple full joins based on `region`?

Thanks!

Comment: Eventually you can cbind() your datasets, e.g. `cbind(BOD, BOD[-1])`

Comment: If your dataframes are called `df1`, `df2`, `df3` etc. You can do `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 'Region'), mget(paste0('df', 1:8)))`